# Kendoui angular2 dropdownlist CUSTOM ITEM TEMPLATE with image

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Does anyone know if it possible to set images in kendo ui angular 2 dropDownlist,
like in kendoui angularjs?

in angularjs:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/angular

can I do the same in kendoUi angular2? 
I tried and it did not work:

```
     <kendo-dropdownlist class="form-control" id="choice"
                                                    [data]="list"
                                                    [textField]="'text'"
                                                    [valueField]="'value'"
                                                    [value]="selectedValue"
                                                    [valuePrimitive]="true">
                                    <template itemTemplate let-dataItem>
                                        <span style="background-image: url('/images/xxx.svg')"></span>
    <span>{{dataItem.text}}</span>
    </template>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can - [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DXdoCfEUd8fkQ70eIcmF?p=preview)

```
 <template itemTemplate let-dataItem>
        {{ dataItem.text }} | {{ dataItem.value }}
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/61/f6/1f/61f61f7873f44d576f325d72453192b9.jpg" />
 </template>
```

Comment: thanks! it works..
But I need the image also in valueTemplate and that does not work for me... is it supported?

Comment: It works just with "hard-coded"/fixed image, I need the image to be dynamic- by the value of the selected data item..

Comment: create a sample so we can see how you include the image :) so we can find a solution for your specific scenario.